# Git merging with upstream master - confusion

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am beginner in git and contributing to a project in github.
What have I done is:

1. Made my own fork of the repo.
2. Added it as origin and added the real one as upstream.
3. Created my own branch from origin master.
4. Been working on it, but upstream/master has moved along.
5. Now my branch is ahead of origin master and origin master is behind upstream master.
6. I still have not pushed my changes to my branch.

My question is what do I need to do before pushing my changes to my branch and raising a PR with the owners?

Thanks a lot, and sorry if stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more efficient way is rebase `my_branch` on the top of `upstream/master` branch, then push `my_branch` on your fork repo, and finally create a PR to merge `my_branch` into the real repo `master` branch. Steps as below:

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull upstream master --rebase
git push origin my_branch
```

If you also want to update origin `master` with the new commit in upstream `master`, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
git push origin master
```

Then you can create a pull request to merge changed from `my_branch` into real repo `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to merge you're code with master and resolve all conflicts, if there are any. When everything is resolved, you can commit and push the merge so that everything gets integrated into the master branch.

Note that you're PR should be reviewed and approved by the owners first before merging.

Comment: So just to confirm:
 1. I need to checkout master

 2. Fetch and merge with upstream master

 3. Push to origin master

 4. Rebase the branch I have been working on to start from the new position of master

 5. Push my branch to origin